# Super constructor cannot be passed a self reference unless parameter is declared by-name

Tags: oop, scala, object

Well, I have something like this:

```
trait A

class Serving(a: => A)

object App extends Serving(App.Main) {
  object Main extends A
}
```

And I get the error `super constructor cannot be passed a self reference unless parameter is declared by-name`. I can work around by doing

```
object App extends Serving(Serv.Main)

object Serv {
  object Main extends A
}
```

but I don't want to. It adds 2 extra `.class`es and it strikes me as unelegant.

And using `object App extends Serving(this.Main)` also creates an error. The structure of `A` and `Serving` cannot really be changed, but is there any way to work around this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code compiles just fine in Scala 2.8.1, even if the parameter is not declared by-name.

Comment: And this example compiles with 2.9.0, too... Okay, 8 hours of coding are too much. Sorry to have bothered you people!