# Object inside class

Tags: scala

Scala 2.12
What is wrong with my implementation?

```
object MyJob extends DatasetReader(x=x) {
  val x = "aaa"
  DatasetReader.read()
}

class DatasetReader(x: String) {
  object DatasetReader {
    def read(): String = {
       // ...
    }
  }
}
```

error:

> super constructor cannot be passed a self reference unless parameter is declared by-name

How to fix it?

Comment: Can't reproduce your error "super constructor cannot be passed..." https://scastie.scala-lang.org/qc5I3DOOT02MkHPNxz1sww The error is "not found: value x".

Comment: Ok, maybe you have import `import MyJob.x`. Then the error is reproducible https://scastie.scala-lang.org/iXdrwmJzTtCayZibqeRIog

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `x=x` ?

Comment: @Thilo I guess OP wants, using named parameter of parent constructor, to refer to object field.

Comment: But that object field will not be initialized yet (which is why the compiler rejects it). Do `x="aaa"` or define it as a constant somewhere else (outside of the the object that is currently being constructed).

Comment: @Thilo Yeap, that's the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option you have is:

```
object MyJob extends {
  val x = "aaa"
} with DatasetReader(x) {
  DatasetReader.read()
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/QChqB3DqTcSmVMb6a4tiWQ/21).

There are similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5996199/2359227) in StackOverflow, [issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10537) in github, and a [bug](https://users.scala-lang.org/t/issue-scala-class-singleton-with-non-default-constructor-parameters/1742) in Scala.

Comment: You beat me with early initializer :)

Comment: That is a very obscure feature (and removed in Scala 3), no need to reach for that. @DmytroMitin can you restore your earlier, much more pragmatic answer, please?

Comment: @Thilo Done .  .

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
val x = "aaa"

object MyJob extends DatasetReader(x=x) {
  DatasetReader.read()
}
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DjB31943QxujtmfrzLa3tg

I guess you can do what you want with early initializer

```
object MyJob extends {
  val x = "aaa"
} with DatasetReader(x=x) {
  DatasetReader.read()
}
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/r6FYtxXeT1SFcFHX6KFM1A

Please notice that early initializers are deprecated in Scala 3

http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/early-initializers.html